# Python - Bind all events from single object

Tags: python, events, bind

In Python, is there a way to bind *every* event generated by an object (perhaps a tkinter widget) to a single function, without explicitly naming them? The motivation here is for learning, debugging and development purposes.

(This question has arisen whilst trying to find a solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894408/python-tkintertreectrl-drag-items).)

Comment: probably not ... you will have to explicitly assign them (there is no generic catchall event for most event system, and I assume TK is no different)

Comment: Thanks - I'll waste no more time on it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to all of the keys like this:

```
def callback(event):
    print(event.char, event.keysym, event.keycode)

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', callback)
root.mainloop()
```